# Anyone know how to get the merchant key for google wallet?

Tags: android-pay

Anyone know how to get the merchant key for goole wallet?

Support indicates I should have an integration menu in settings but the menu is not showing up

http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42963

Thanks

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `merchant key` is only relevant to "legacy" Google Checkout - re: your account must be for Google Wallet for Web sites (products/services sold at your web site).

The `merchant key` referenced in the support link you have, is used (only for) *that specific API*.

Comment: Thanks, its very confusing trying to simply add digital download to an app.

Comment: "Web app"? Have you looked at [Wallet for digital goods](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/)?

Comment: Yes, it was my intention to use the Wallet for digital goods but I seem to have stumbled into the checkout documentation. I've got the wallet mostly working just need to figure out how to send the HTTP response from my php file.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Wallet integration settings page is at https://checkout.google.com/inapp/merchant/settings.html .

For some reason, this page is not accessible from anywhere within the Google Wallet merchant interface.