# Google checkout transactions for google play account

Tags: android, api, google-play, google-checkout, android-pay

Situation:

1. Our company has an application in Google Play. Application uses in-app purchases and information about payment transactions are shown in google checkout.
2. Our company used in-house analytics system to see how many payments are done, how much money we got, etc.
3. I need to create some way to fetch information about payments from google play/checkout(#1) to our system (#2).

According to research in Internet, I found following ways to do that:

1. Polling API
2. Notification History API
3. Order Report API

All this sysstems will work for me, however, I need somehow to get Merchand Key in order to be able to request data from system.

Merchant key should be located in Settings -> integration, however, our company google checkout account has no "integration tab". According to interenet, reason is that we are not "standart merchant but google play merchant".

Questions are:

1. How to get information from google play about payments ?
2. Is there any other way to do such thing, for example directly from google play ?
3. Or, is there any other way to get merchant key ?

I am totally newbie in Android or google play so desperately need help.

Comment: See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14016454/304683). The APIs you mention are for "legacy" Google Checkout (so is the merchant key).